# AKS Cluster deployment fails with "ReconcileMSICredentialError"

Tags: azure, azure-aks

When I try to deploy a fresh AKS cluster with "Dev/Test" Settings via the Portal, I get the following error while deployment:

```
{"code":"DeploymentFailed","message":"At least one resource deployment operation failed.
Please list deployment operations for details. Please see 
https://aka.ms/DeployOperations for usage details.","details":
[{"code":"ReconcileMSICredentialError","message":"Reconcile MSI credential failed. 
Details: autorest/azure: Service returned an error. Status=409 Code=\"Conflict\" 
Message=\"Secret bf905bf9e9ad86526b26e98d2ea490a0a500ff23907f9df987d95de3a649e751 is 
currently being deleted and cannot be re-created; retry later.\" InnerError=
{\"code\":\"ObjectIsBeingDeleted\"}."}]}
```

However, the resource still gets deployed, but with a notification that "the resource is in a failed state". When I stop the cluster and start it new, the notification disappears but I'm not sure if the error remains.

I can avoid the error altogether, if I pick a new name for the cluster. However, I'd like to keep the old name.

The same happens when I deploy with different settings (CPU, number of nodes, etc.). I also tried deleting the cluster entirely and deploying it completely new but the error persists. I haven't found any explanation to this error either on Stackoverflow or Google.

What could be the reason for this error and how to avoid it?

Answer (score 0):

***I tried to reproduce the same issue in my environment and got the below results***

*I have created the AKS cluster with dev/test environment*

[image]

*The reference cluster is successfully created*

[image]

*I have given the some credentials to the cluster using below command*

```
az aks get-credentials --resource-group Alldemorg --name cluster_name
```

[image]

*Created the sample application and deployed that application into the cluster,

I have used the following [Reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/learn/quick-kubernetes-deploy-portal?tabs=azure-cli) for example sample file.*

[image]

*Deployment got succeeded and I am able to see all the pods and nodes which got created  for the application*

[image]

***Note:***

*1). "ReconcileMSICredentialError" error we are getting because of the version please check the version and upgrade to latest*

*2). If the resource is in failed stated delete the entire resource instead of deleting cluster and create it again if we stop and start the resource may chance of getting "ReconcileMSICredentialError".*